# Android studio firebase banner ads id not working with intertial ads ids

Tags: android-studio, firebase, admob, interstitial, banner-ads

I have use banner ads in my app and want to add interstitial ads too with same firebase ad mob project. How can I do it? I have use banner id with the interstitial ads id but when I do it, it doesn't display it. Help me to get out of this. Add interstitial ads in fire-base ad mob projects which already banner ads id have in that project.

```
  mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(" ca-app-pub-6314200474000962/6862626336");
    requestNewInterstitial();
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            requestNewInterstitial();
        }
    });

    requestNewInterstitial();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly call `mInterstitialAd.show()` at whatever natural breakpoint in your app you intend on showing the interstitial.

Comment: friend actual what i really want is . in android studio 2.3 added a feature of integrating fire base ad-mob in tool>fire-base it self but through that i have implemented the banner ads and want to implement the interstitial ads too but when i have implemented the banner ads i am not able to find how to implement interstitial ads through that menu it will help me very much if you explain me how to implement other types of ads then banner ads with that integrated fire-base menu with android studio .